# datepicker.js not working as expected

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I'm trying to add a date picker to a form. I'm supposed to use [datepicker.js](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js) to do this.

I've included the js files in my file, and I've followed the little bit of instructions on the site, but mine isn't acting like I expect it to. Instead of displaying a pop-up calendar to select a date from when you focus on the input field, the field is unclickable, and the calendar is always visible right under it.

Here's what I'm currently using:

```
<input class="datepicker" placeholder="Select a departure date&hellip;"></input>
    <script>
        $(".datepicker").pickadate()
    </script>
```

Does anyone have any advice for me, or can anyone point me at a decent tutorial(I haven't been able to find one)

Comment: which browser are you using?

Comment: What is this?
  
        $(".datepicker").pickadate()

Comment: @amit I am using Chrome for testing quickly after I change something, but it's actually for mobile safari

Comment: @Kalyan that's the jquery you use to create a datepicker calender like  the one I linked in my question

Comment: Hey I know that but, Is pickadate() is a plug in?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. `pickadate()` is part of the datepicker.js - it's used to create the popover calendar that I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem: Some of the styling in the datepicker's `main.css` was being overridden in another css file. I renamed some styles and changed others, and it's working now.

Answer (score 2):

Replace this

```
<input class="datepicker" placeholder="Select a departure date&hellip;"></input>
```

With this one

```
<input class="datepicker" placeholder="Select a departure date&hellip;" />
```

Comment: What is difference between both the lines?

Comment: the input tag isn't correct , check this snapshot to know what am talking about http://prntscr.com/1oawrv

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud, but this didn't solve my problem. Both act the same way.

Answer (score 2):

why dont you use the Datepicker api from Jquery UI, it works just the way you are expecting it for

**JS CODE**

```
$(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
});
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/PjARV/) at JSFIDDLE

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Thanks dreamweiver, but with or without wrapping it in a function like that it acts the same

Comment: @Skytiger: I didnt get you , can you be more specific  on what you mean by `but with or without wrapping it in a function like that it acts the same`

Comment: @Skytiger: if you have found this helpful, then check this as "Answer" and close the Question. this will reduce the number of Open Questions from SO :)

Comment: what I meant with my comment is that using your suggestion or not, it's still not working correctly. I don't want to mark it as answered if I haven't solved my problem yet, thanks.

Comment: @Skytiger: ok, can u tell me what problem your facing.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like that framework doesnt provide the same funcitonality as seen on the demopage by default. I've written a little fiddle to show how you can use it- it works but I'm sure it wasnt intended to work that way :D

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pBbc7/)

```
  <input />
    <script>
$('input').click(function () {
    var oldInput = $(this); //save this for using in the onSet event
    var newInput = $(this).clone(true); //clone old input to prevent weird changes from datepicker.js
    $(this).pickadate({
        onSet: function (event) { //occurs when something is selected
            console.log('Just set stuff:', event)
            if(event.highlight == undefined){  //is false when changing months         
            $(oldInput).next().remove(); //hide picker
            $(newInput).val($(oldInput).val()); //save value from weird generated input
            $(oldInput).before(newInput); //place new normal input
            $(oldInput).remove(); // remove weirt input
            }
        }
    })
});
    </script>
```

Comment: superb this is what i was looking for . I have one request. If i have more than two input field and and i wanna remove the picker from one if opened other .How to do this ?

Comment: if i get your question right this should be the solution. 
http://jsfiddle.net/KyZ35/

Comment: Max its working good with input tag . But when i am trying with div tag its not working . can you please help.

<div class="book">1231233</div>
<div class="book">1231233</div>
<div class="book">1231233</div>
<div class="book">1231233</div>

$('.book').click(function () {   })
I am trying something like this

Comment: Here's an altered version of your code - http://jsfiddle.net/8GQ5A/ - if you need any further help, please create a fiddle or similar describing your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $(".datepicker").datepicker({
        format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
    }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
        $(this).blur();
        $(this).datepicker('hide');
   });
```

Comment: thats jquery ui's datepicker. OP is trying to use a different datepicker.